# How to mock static method using junit and easymock

Tags: java, junit, easymock, jmock

The problem is next: I need to test method **methodTest()** of private class. 
The **methodTest()** call static method ***staticExternal()*** from external library.
How to replace the ***staticExternal()*** on a *mockLocal()*, if I use JMock and EasyMock, but class that contains the ***staticExternal()*** haven't interface?

P.S. PowerMock can not be used.

Comment: possibly this question is already answered in [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162551/how-do-i-mock-static-methods-in-a-class-with-easymock) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218813/jmock-mocking-a-static-method)

Comment: Why are you rejecting PowerMock, when it's the simple and correct solution to the problem you have?  If you want a constrained answer, you'll have to explain why.

Comment: @AndrewAylett I know that PowerMock is good framework. Unfortunately,  I have such exercise. Thanks all!

Comment: use power mock http://www.michaelminella.com/testing/how-to-mock-static-methods.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, as far as I'm aware. Basically that code is hard to test. You should consider extracting a dependency, where the "normal" implementation of that dependency calls the static method.

Fundamentally, static method calls are hard to replace precisely because they're static. Tools like PowerMock have to furtle with the guts of Java (replacing classloaders etc) in order to intercept static method calls. In my opinion it's *usually* better to refactor your code so that it's testable without that sort of thing.