# EasyMock number of "expected" calls is greater than the value set in "times" method

Tags: java, mocking, easymock

When refactoring some old unit tests, I added a `verify()` call to see how many times a method was being expected and was surprised to see that the "expected" calls was greater than  what was set using `times()`. For some reason the expect call on the next line is being added to my method.

Why is this happening?

**Test Class**

```
public class SandBoxTest {    
    @Test
    public void shouldGetSand() {
        Sand niceMock = EasyMock.createNiceMock(Sand.class);

        EasyMock.expect(niceMock.sandMethod()).andReturn(1).times(2);
        EasyMock.expect(Box.boxMethod()).andReturn(99).times(11);

        EasyMock.replay(niceMock);

        EasyMock.verify(niceMock);
    }
}
```

**Output When Run**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Expectation failure on verify:
    Sand.sandMethod(): expected: 13, actual: 0
```

**Output That Was Expected**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Expectation failure on verify:
    Sand.sandMethod(): expected: 2, actual: 0
```

***Details:** EasyMock v3.1*

***Followup:** Opened feature request with EasyMock. https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/EASYMOCK-128*

Comment: By `Box` do you mean `sandBox` and how is that initialized?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No, sandBox is actually irrelevant; I updated the code to remove it. There are no concrete classes or implementations in this test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's what's up.

[The javadoc for `expect()` states](http://easymock.org/api/easymock/3.1/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#expect%28T%29)

> **expect(T value)**
>      Returns the expectation setter for the last expected invocation in the current thread.

With these calls

```
EasyMock.expect(niceMock.sandMethod()).andReturn(1).times(2);
EasyMock.expect(Box.boxMethod()).andReturn(99).times(11);
```

The last expected invocation is, in both cases, `niceMock.sandMethod()` since it's the only Mock method call, so it adds `2+11 = 13`.

EasyMock's mocked object have some counter in the proxy that registers what was called.

`Box.boxMethod()` is just a static method call. You can't mock that. [Or maybe you can.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162551/how-do-i-mock-static-methods-in-a-class-with-easymock)

Comment: That is weird. I can believe that is what is happening, but I that javadoc is... not easily understood. Also I would have expected that EasyMock would throw an exception on the expect call to a static method.

Comment: @Mike Try calling a static method that has a different return type.

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: incompatible return value type` Still would prefer an except along the lines of "can not mock static methods"

Comment: @MikeRylander I'm assuming your static method had same return type as your `sandMethod()` so the last expected can be returned. And I agree with you, it's not clear.