# EasyMock - Expecting a method call which is static

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

How does one use EasyMock in order to test static functions that cannot be overridden? I have one large test suite class, and I partially mock an object 'A' inside of my test suite. As i mock my object 'A', is there any way to expect these static method calls which take in arguments?

For the sake of the code, classes A and B have to stay in their current position and cannot be rearranged due to outside dependencies. Class 'A' makes a call onto bar() from class 'B'. I need to be able to mock method foo() or method bar(), however they are static and take in arguments.

Class in question:

```
class A extends B {
    public static void foo(args...) {
        ...
        bar(args...);
    }
}

class B {
    public static void bar(args...) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I mock static methods in a class with easymock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162551/how-do-i-mock-static-methods-in-a-class-with-easymock)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you cannot do it with easymock.

See a similar question here:

[How do I mock static methods in a class with easymock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162551/how-do-i-mock-static-methods-in-a-class-with-easymock)

Comment: Thank you. Upon further research you are correct. I was hoping there was a hacky method around doing so.

Comment: No. You need Powermock on top of EasyMock to do it

Comment: @Henri - Could you please suggest how can we do this with PowerMock ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. But reading the PowerMock documentation should have given you the same answer in 5 minutes.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ B.class})
public class MyTest {

  @Test
  public void test() {
    mockStatic(B.class); // Mock static methods on B
    B.bar(4); // Record a static call to B.bar expecting 4 in argument

    replay(B.class); // Go in replay mode

    A.foo(4); // Call foo that will then call bar(4)

    verify(B.class); // Verify that B.bar(4) was indeed called 
  }

}
```