# How to mock static void methods using EasyMock only?

Tags: java, methods, static, void, easymock

I want to mock A.notNull(obj) method in my TestB.java class using EasyMock. I am struggling to mock this method since one week.

```
//A.class
public class A
{
    public static void notNull(Object o)
    {
       notNull(o,"object is null");
    }
    public static void notNull(Object o, String s)
    { 
       if (o==null)
       {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException(s);   
       }
    }
 }

 //B.class
 Class<? extends E> obj;

 protected final Simple limit()
 {
     A.notNull(obj); //I want to mock this line in my TestB.java class using EasyMock framework
 }
```

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: Easy mock does not support Static mocking, you need to use powermock along with easymock for it.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response, but I am bound with EasyMock framework. Please suggest any other way with EasyMock itself.

Comment: This is internal implementation detail and could be reasonably replaced by inlining the null check. Don't mock it; instead, confirm that `B` performs correctly when presented with a `null`.

Comment: Not a good solution but still used at some places https://stackoverflow.com/a/12193017/4762502

Comment: Class B performs null check correctly. It is giving class name in obj field.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, EasyMock doesn't support mocking static methods. You need to add PowerMock on top of it to do so.

However, in your case, I would indeed not mock `notNull`. It doesn't do anything that requires mocking. You don't even need this method since `Objects.requireNotNull` does the same thing.